# Pandas will not import in Command Prompt

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to run a .bat file on a schedule. The file works fine in PyCharm. Runs all the way through. However, when I open the.bat file I get this error.

```
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

So I then import numpy normally in command prompt.

```
In: python
In: import numpy
out:   from . import _mklinit
ImportError: cannot import name '_mklinit' from 'numpy' (C:\Users\user\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py)
```

I don't know what _mklinit is or where to find it. I then followed the same steps except in the Anaconda prompt this time and it worked beautifully. 
I do have two pythons install, #1 from Anaconda and #2 from Python itself. I've tried both python.exe path and none seem to work.

Comment: Very likely that you have different python interpreters installed in your machine. In `PyCharm`, you have linked your project to a specific python interpreter that has numpy installed and is able to run the script just nice. When you open the .bat, you likely use the default `e.g. /usr/bin/python` which may not have numpy installed (or might be installed with an incompatible version).

Comment: Usually, it should be specified explicitly what python should be used to open a specific script. Worst case scenario, go to your PyCharm and check which environment you're using and which py interpreter, and run your bat calling *that* python interpreter

Comment: okay  will check out the solution in a little bit and get back to you

Comment: @rafaelc I just checked my interpreter and it's the same path as the one in my bat.